# Problems to extend the content of a div until the end of its container in a layout

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am trying to develop a personal version of this working template that use CSS3: http://www.html.it/articoli/1688/template/photoshop-xhtml-css.html

And this is my version of the previous template: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

As you can see the two templates are very very similar in the structure and in the css settings (I have recreated it in Photoshop and the I have use the same HTML\CSS structure using CSS3 for the shadow and doing some litle change)

As you can see I have some problem with the left sidebar because the last blue box (the #c div) does not extend vertically to the end of the #container div and so don't match with the footer background immage.

**The strange thing is that this problems disappear and appears changing the browser magnification with CTRL + and CTRL -**

The only "solution" that I have found (but this is not a correct solution) is to increase the value of the min-height* property of the **#c div of my sidebare. For example if I increase this value from the original 234px to 334px it seems to work well.

But this is not a real solution because if the amount of content change of the page change this problem occurs again.

It seems to me quite strange because the structure is almost the same of the original layout.

What is the difference that causes this problem?
How can I solve? What can I do to extend the height of the #c div until the end of its container

Comment: Typical multi-column layout problem. One of the solutions is to make a background image/color for the parent container of the menu, so it visually makes the menu longer. Here is a nice tutorial on two-column layout: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Answer (score 0):

try setting the width to 100%.

Also, use padding on the body, set the nav lower (margin-top), your cerca search picture is not working, check the file path and float your footer to the right.